# Submit form as component

Tags: next.js, axios, prisma, zod, shadcnui

I'm doing a project where it includes crud capabilities, I'm using forms as media for create and update, I'm currently turning and tumbling my brain over and around over implementing the update functionality, I've now come up with a solution (I think is feasible), which is using dynamic routing as a way to call the specific form update page for the record that needs updating.

```
'use client';
import Header from '@/components/Header';
import axios from 'redaxios';
import ClimbingBoxLoader from 'react-spinners/ClimbingBoxLoader';
import { Warga } from '@prisma/client';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import FormComponent from '@/components/FormComponent';

export default function UpdateFormPage({
  params,
}: {
  params: { slug: string };
}) {
  const [warga, setWarga] = useState<Warga | null>(null); // Initially, wargaData is set to null

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = () => {
      axios
        .get(`/api/warga/${params.slug}`)
        .then((response) => {
          const wargaData = response.data;
          setWarga(wargaData);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        });
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [params.slug]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className='container mx-auto my-8 flex-col md:flex'>
        <Header></Header>
        <div className='container mx-auto xl:px-96'>
          <h1 className='text-center text-4xl my-8 font-bold'>
            <a href='/'>Update Warga Form</a>
          </h1>
          {warga !== null ? (
            <FormComponent warga={warga}></FormComponent>
          ) : (
            <div className='h-96 flex items-center justify-center overflow-hidden'>
              <ClimbingBoxLoader
                color={'#bbbbbb'}
                loading={true}
                size={60}
                aria-label='Loading Spinner'
                data-testid='loader'
              />
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

since I'm fetching the data using useeffect, it doesn't instantly fetch the data before the form render, so I decided to put the form as its own component, so that I can pass the data when it actually arrives

```
'use client';

// Imports and Types

export default function FormComponent({ warga }: any) {
  const { toast } = useToast();

  // Form Definition

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      // Default Values fetched from the props
    },
  });

  // Submit handler.
  async function onSubmit(values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) {
    try {
      const response = await axios.patch(`/api/warga/${warga?.nik}`, values);

      if (response.data) {
        toast({
          description: 'Success',
        });
        location.reload();
      } else {e
        toast({
          description: 'Fail',
          variant: 'destructive',
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error submitting form:', error);
      toast({
        description: 'An error occurred while submitting the form',
        variant: 'destructive',
      });
    }
  }

  const statusPekerjaan = form.watch('statusPekerjaan');

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form
        onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        className='space-y-8'
      >
        // Form content
        <Button
          type='submit'
          disabled={form.formState.isSubmitting}
        >
          {form.formState.isSubmitting ? 'Submitting...' : 'Submit'}
        </Button>
      </form>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

Now the problem here is, when I click submit, it doesn't do anything, it doesn't even display the submitting loader, which makes me think the problem is that the form doesn't detect that I'm submitting when I click the form, can anyone help me out on this? TIA

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the reason the submit handler isn't working is because useForm's submit handler only goes off after validating the form, and there is a part of my form that was hidden that I forgot to check, after I've handled the missing value from the defaultValues it worked as per usual